# Matlab -plot a vector field

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot

I have written a function in Matlab that gives me a vector at a position (x,y,z).

Now I am looking for the easiest way to make a colored map of this field on a grid and the color should be related to the norm of the vector.

What is the easiest way to define such a grid for $x \in [x_0,x_1],y \in [y_0,y_1], z \in [z_0,z_1]$? Probably linspace for each component would be possible, but maybe there is already a command that gives me the grid.

Now I need to evaluate my function. The problem is, that it actually gives me two vectors, but I am only interested in the first one. So when I first tried to do this I thought that $[A(i,j,k),~]=function(x(i),y(j),z(k))$ could work, but it did not(My goal was: Choose the first vector(A) and mark him with the reference(i,j,k), so that you later on know to which coordinates this vector belongs to).

So I am highly interested in any kind of ideas.

Comment: Your function returns a displacement vector you want to plot on the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
[A(i,j,k),~]=function(x(i),y(j),z(k));
```

try

```
[A(i,j,k,:),~]=function(x(i),y(j),z(k));
```

so that you can fit the entire size of the 3-coordinate vector. Also, if you want to preallocate space use

```
 A = zeros(Nx,Ny,Nz,3);
```

where `Nx,...` are the dims of your coordinate space. Then like @Moly explains, use `meshgrid` to generate a 3D grid,

```
 [X Y Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
```

and loop or vectorize to resolve values of your function at points `X(i,j,k),Y(i,j,k),Z(i,j,k)`, compute the `norm` and store it in 3D array `C`.

**Edit**

Representing a cube with `mesh(X,Y,Z,C)` is not possible but individual slices of the 3D cube can be visualized with `mesh`, setting the height `Z` equal to the result of the function `C`. Some additional work is then required to get coloring right.

Yet another alternative is to use `pcolor` or `contourf`. This is perhaps the easiest way to show the 4D data beyond creating a 3D isosurface.

code:

```
figure
colormap(jet)
for ii=1:9
    subplot(3,3,ii)
    pcolor(X(:,:,ii),Y(:,:,ii),F(:,:,ii))
    axis('equal','square'), title(['Z=' num2str(ii)])
    caxis([0 1])
end
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, altough i have not tested your answer yet, it seems though as if it would answer my questions

Comment: okay, thank you. well I arrived at the last point. I actually have now x=linspace(a,b,10) and the same for y and z. so they contain 10 numbers. further, i have f, which is a 10x10x10 matrix with the absolute value of my vector and now i entered mesh(x,y,z,f) and then I received: Error using mesh (line 76)
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector

Comment: further i should tell you that f(i,j,k)=norm(vector(x(i),y(j),z(k)))

Comment: but in your explanation i do not see what it is actually good for? so i should enter meshgrid[x,y,z] and get xg yg and zg. what are then X Y and Z that enter mesh are they x y z or xg yg and zg?

Comment: exactly, the notation in my answer was confusing... X=xg etc... I'll change that now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35028/discussion-between-lipschitz-and-try-hard)

Comment: sorry, have one further question

Comment: have written it in the chat

Answer (score 2):

The function `meshgrid` might be what you are looking for to generate the x, y and z coordinates.